# Re-Projection of a .sid image file

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, arccatalog, digital-image-processing, mrsid

Does anyone know if I can use ArcMap or ArcCatalog to change the projection of a .sid img without changing it to a .tiff? I have tried the project raster tool but it changes it to a .tiff which will not be usable for the outcome I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  You need proprietary software to produce .sid files.

Comment: That was my conclusion but I figured I would reach out! Thank you!